# image with a height in percent

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with horizontal image "gallery" where I set the **height to 100%** and **don't set the width** of the picture due to different sizes.

My problem is that the parent element does not diminish and he remains the original width of the image. Try **resize height of window** for display problem. Red color is parent.

**I need this:** parent image will have a height of 70% and will be centered vertically, the image will set its height to 100% and will automatically change the width according to the resolution.

How it look -> http://prntscr.com/2qkoj8

It must be solved in css.

My problem can be seen on http://helpimage.honzabittner.cz/

Thank you for help and sorry for my English... :)

Comment: You have some values on the containers `margin-right` that's why you see all that space .. remove that values an d you will see

Comment: You should put in your question **anything** you've tried so far. Any information you could provide will encourage other users to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update

you can try something like

```
<div id="project-eagle" class="project">
    <img src="project/eagle/01.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="what">....</div>
</div>
```

set project to display inline

Now this gets rid of the issue where the container does not resize properly but it does not vertically center your content. You will have to do something with that but this is as close as I can get without js

Comment: what do you mean it's not working, you still have it as inline-block and not inline for p-one

Comment: Try add display inline in chrome, it's not working... :(

Comment: works for me, you don't see any red when reducing the height of the window. Update the site as in my answer and let me see what you mean

Comment: Now it's update. Red does not show, but the width is still preserved.

Comment: I see, it's due to your project container

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to remove the margin-right:14px; in class project p-one